# Two PCF8574 detected but not the third PCF8574

Tags: arduino, i2c, io, expander

I'll be using an Arduino Nano 33 IoT together with three [PCF8574](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcf8574.pdf) IO expander boards. I've managed to connect two PCF8574s together and communicate to each of them individually at different address buses of 0x20 and 0x21 respectively. However, when I connected the third PCF8574, there was no response from my Arduino Nano 33 IoT and the I2C bus.

When I connect two PCF8574 (0x20 and 0x21) together, I receive this in my serial port:

[image: Serial port of 0x20 and 0x21]

[image: 2 PCF8574 connected together]

However, after adding the third PCF8574, everything on my Arduino stopped responding.

[image: After adding the third PCF8574]

[image: third PCF8574 connected]

The code of my I2C scanner is shown below:

```
while (!Serial);
Serial.println("I2C Scanner");

for (uint8_t address = 1; address < 127; address++) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(address);
  if (Wire.endTransmission() == 0) {
    Serial.print("Found Device at address 0x");
    if (address < 16)
      Serial.print("0"); 
    Serial.println(address,HEX);
  }
}
```

Does anyone have any clues because I've been trying to figure this out for the longest time and have tried various ways, but was not able to get it connected.

Comment: Does all combinations of two out of three work?

Comment: It does work if i interchange 0x20 and 0x22 or 0x21 and 0x22. The moment i added the 3rd device, everything stops working.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is obvious, if you look at the board instead of the chip data sheet.

Each board has pull-up resistors on SDA and SCL. They are R1 and R2.

The bus has too strong pull-ups in total if all modules have their own pull-up resistors, so communication is impossible.

The board manual or website should mention these things.

Either use less modules or remove all pull-ups except for one set on one board, preferably leave the Arduino pull-ups it has them.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer. As i would require a minimal of 3 PCF8574, I might not be able to use less modules. Which leaves me with the second option of removing the pulls -up, how do I remove the pull-ups for all?

Comment: @ArduinoRookie You can remove them in any way you want as long as there is no damage to the circuits you need. You can e.g. solder them off so you can later put them back if you need. Assuming you have the tools and skills to do that, which means a soldering iron meant for electronics, not roofing. Or cut the PCB trace with a knife from a suitable spot. Or buy different modules with detachable pull-ups if they have settable jumpers.

Comment: I see, thank you! If i were to remove the R1 and R2 resistors, does it interfere with the serial communications as there will not be pull up resistors for one of the PCF8574?

Comment: @ArduinoRookie I already said it is a problem that there are too many pull-ups and you can remove everything except one set which should preferably be on the MCU board. So no, removing them will not interfere, it will make it work. Having too strong pull-ups in total does interfere.

Comment: Okay thank you very much! So I will leave the pull-ups of the Arduino and remove all the pull-ups from my 3 PCF8574.